# encoding required to create a file with name contains charector ®

Tags: java, file, encoding

I have to create a file with name **FicheBail sign+®eDC.pdf** i have used utf-8, cp437 etc

```
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);
zout.setEncoding("Encoding type  ");
```

but non working for me. They are resulting strange results please help me

Please let me know **®e** what type of encoding required for this.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF8 can certainly accommodate this file name, as can many legacy encodings, such as Latin-1. Your problem is most likely a file system problem; many legacy file systems specify a particular character set for local file names. Without more information about your platform, only a general answer can be formulated.